# Limits of f(x) and f'(x)

Tags: real-analysis

Let f is differentiable function from R to R and if lim f'(x) is non zero or infinite  as x approaches  to infinity,
Then what we tell about the behavior  of f(x) when x approaches to infinity

I take some examples  of such functions and noticed that f(x) is unbounded in such case ,but unable  to proof it.

Comment: Your conjecture is correct! The Mean Value Theorem is a tool that can help you prove this, perhaps by contradiction (assume that $f$ is bounded in a region where $f'(x)$ is bounded away from $0$ due to its limiting behavior...).

Comment: Please provide  full proof ,unable to get it